# Bulleting/ Format Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, formatting

I am copying and pasting bulleted lists on Sharepoint. When I press enter to go to the next line and try to continue the bulleted list, it automatically indents it and will not allow the bullet points to be in a straight line down the page. I would like for them to all align yet there must be some formatting issue that I do not know how to fix. The bullet list is cascading.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot where you are trying this?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint will add new paragraphs if you hit enter. So it 'breaks' the HTML code that creates the <LI> elements

I *think* you have to use ctrl-Enter or Shift-enter (or some other key combo)